# select the characters in after "):" and print it in between?

Tags: python

I have a file like this

```
(E:0.13228,((D:0.08440,A:0.14071):0.29270,(H:0.30329,(B:0.06928,
(F:0.00236,G:0.00010):0.00010):0.44531):0.06201):0.57269,C:0.19183);
```

I need to generate it as follows:

```
(E:0.13228,((D:0.08440,A:0.14071)0.29270:0.29270,(H:0.30329,(B:0.06928,
(F:0.00236,G:0.00010)0.00010:0.00010)0.44531:0.44531)0.06201:0.06201)0.57269:0.57269,C:0.19183);
```

Comment: Try it and if you get an error, then we will help/assist you. It is more fun.

Comment: Question is not clear

Comment: @Gijo Don't provide clarification in the comments. Change your post.

Comment: Its easy to do in perl.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you should use in this cases are the regular expressions. Check [Python re](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html)

```
match_pattern = r'\):(\d(\.\d+)?)'
output_pattern = r')\1:\1'

input_str = """(E:0.13228,((D:0.08440,A:0.14071):0.29270,(H:0.30329,(B:0.06928,
(F:0.00236,G:0.00010):0.00010):0.44531):0.06201):0.57269,C:0.19183);"""

output_str = re.sub(match_pattern, output_pattern, input_str)

print(output_str)
```

And the result is:

```
(E:0.13228,((D:0.08440,A:0.14071)0.29270:0.29270,(H:0.30329,(B:0.06928,
(F:0.00236,G:0.00010)0.00010:0.00010)0.44531:0.44531)0.06201:0.06201)0.57269:0.57269,C:0.19183);
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess you could go with some string manipulation like so if you're not using regular expressions

```
data = "(E:0.13228,((D:0.08440,A:0.14071):0.29270,(H:0.30329,(B:0.06928, 
        (F:0.00236,G:0.00010):0.00010):0.44531):0.06201):0.57269,C:0.19183);"
dataParts = data.split("):")

correctedData = dataParts[0]
for dataPart in dataParts[1:]:
    number = dataPart[:7]
    correctedData = "){}:".format(number).join([correctedData, dataPart])
```

but that's not clean...